# Changing the whole page while keeping a div open

Tags: php, html

I simplified my real php page just to get an idea, I have this simple php page with a div, I want to keep this div open and its input with the text that has been changed by the user, when I change the page and go to page2.php

```
<html>
<head> stuff.. </head>
<body>
    stuff in the body.. 
    <div>I want this div to stay in the other page, (without cloning it)
        <input type="text" value="hello" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: just save the user input in a session and transfer it in the next page using the same session values

Comment: or keep the same page and make an xmlhttprequest and put the page 2 in the current page

Comment: @Kevin Thank you, but how would I change everything with xmlhttprequest without  single DIV, and I don't think it would load js files of this 2nd page too (and the "on document load" of it, etc)